# mkdir giving false warning when creating a directory

Tags: php, mkdir

I am trying to create a temporary directory but I am getting  following error

`Warning: mkdir(): File exists`

However when i checked the directory actually doesn't exist.A typical value for `$tmp` is `/tmp/testKanfEt`

```
$tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir() , 'test');
echo  $tmp;
mkdir($tmp);
```

What am i missing here ?

Comment: Because you check after your script is over and all tmp files are removed?

Comment: But `tempnam` already creates file

Comment: possible duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/why-cant-i-have-a-folder-and-a-file-with-the-same-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `tempnam()` **creates** a file in given path **and** returns the full path if created successfully. You are attempting to make a directory with the **same** *path as the file*.

---

But in this case, `tempnam()` is being used wrongly in my opinion.
It should be used when trying to make *tmp* files in any other directory than the o.s. *tmp* folder.

Why? Because making files in the *tmp* directory you should not care about the file name because once the *lock* has been released on a file (with `fclose()` or end of script execution for example) you cannot guarantee the file still being there.

---

Instead, use [tmpfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php) as it returns a file handle directly creating a file in the *tmp* directory.

And if you really need the file name, you still could use `tempnam()` or retreive it from the handle like so:

```
echo stream_get_meta_data(($fh=tempfile()))["uri"];
```